# Verification Displaying 0000 Only on PHP Contact Us Form

Tags: php, image, forms, magento, verification

We have a simple PHP contact us form that we have setup, which works fine on it's own as can be seen here :

http://gadgetfreakz.co.uk/help/contact.phtml

However when implemented into magento through CMS Pages it will not display any other verification other than 0000:

http://gadgetfreakz.co.uk/contactus

I have directly linked the image.php file to a root folder, this changed it from not displaying an image to displaying 0000.

I believe the issue is in the contact-form.php, I have zipped the entire contact us form as the code was too long to be posted which can be found here :

http://gadgetfreakz.co.uk/help/contactform.zip

Thank you very much!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot have [PHP code in CMS pages](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3698/). That link provides several workarounds. I don't know if those solutions will work for you, the session stuff might cause problems.

Comment: I did actually follow this post to get this far: 'So it looks like we can have php code in phtml file and call this file from CMS block. '